# jQuery Remove second class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example: `<h3 class="first second">Text</h3>`
How can remove html second class?

Hope can see that `<h3 class="first">Text</h3>`
I try the code but doesn't work.

```
$( "h3" ).removeClass( "first second" ).addClass( "first" );
```

Have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have SHOULD be working as long a jQuery is on the page.

No need to remove both then re-add; you can search on either class then remove that second one as desired:

```
$("h3.second").removeClass("second");
```

OR

```
$("h3.first").removeClass("second");
```

OR

```
$("h3.first.second").removeClass("second");
```

Comment: I guess the first one or the last one will be the best way depending upon need.Second one might run in vain if the class already doesn't exist.

Comment: @Roy - yes unless you simply wanted it to do that for some obtuse reasoning - which produces no error , simply added that example to be complete.

Answer (score 5):

Generic solution..

var className=$('.first').attr('class').split(' ')[1];

$( "h3" ).removeClass( className );

Answer (score 3):

Just `removeClass()` also will do the trick. Your code looks right,but if still facing issue,kindly provide us with a fiddle

**[removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)**

```js
$( "h3" ).removeClass( "second" );
```

```css
 .first {
    color: blue;
  }
  .second {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="first second">Text</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's your mean for 'second' ?

```js
var whichIndexYouWantRemove = 1;
var classString = $( "h3" ).attr('class');
var classes = classString.split(" ");
classes.splice(whichIndexYouWantRemove,1);
var newClassString = classes.join(' ');
$('#result').text(newClassString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="aaa bbb ccc ddd eee">
Hello Guys
</h3>

<div id="result">
...
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/821vmoj4/1/